# In some cases, the arrows in menuitem are displayed incorrectly

Tags: javafx

After some manipulations with the visibility of the context menu items, I get the following picture

[image]

(the arrows in submenus are displayed incorrectly)

Can you tell me what this might be related to and how to avoid it?
I don't really understand how to deal with this

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve].  Ensure that you are using the latest stable version of JavaFX.

Comment: might be related to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8238730 - if so, not resolved yet

Comment: Yes, this is clearly it))) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using setStyle set the width of the menu items equal to the width of the longest item, then the problem is solved.
Something like this

```
String style = "-fx-pref-width :" + Double.toString(max_width) + ";";
    for (int i = 0; i < subMenu.getItems().size(); i++) {
        subMenu.getItems().get(i).setStyle(style);
```

Text width of the item can be calculated in this way

```
static public double getTextWidth(String str) {
    Text tmp = new Text(str);   
    new Scene(new Pane(tmp));   
    tmp.applyCss();
    return tmp.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();        
}
```